# How to match a quiz answer to two different cases?

Tags: swift, enums

I am making a simple personality quiz but I want some of my answers to fall under multiple personality types, not just one.

Here is working code where answers attribute to one specific PersonalityType:

```
var questions: [Question] = [
        Question(text: "Pick one that best describes you", //Single choice answers
                 type: .single,
                 answers: [
                    Answer(text: "Healthy", type: .extrovert,),
                    Answer(text: "Average", type: .average),
                    Answer(text: "Unfit", type: .neuro),
   
        ]),
```

I want to achieve something along the lines of `Answer(text: "Healthy", type: .extrovert, .fit),` So that answering Healthy matches a 'extrovert' and 'fitness' personality type.

I think it's because I am using enum to record Personality Type String:

```
struct Answer {
    var text: String
    var type: PersonalityType
    
}

enum PersonalityType: String {
    case fit = "Fitness", extrovert = "Extrovert", average = "Average", neuro = "Neuroticism" //personality type
```

Comment: How about declaring `type` as an array? `var type: [PersonalityType]`

Answer (score 0):

1. In Answer struct use `var type: [PersonalityType]` instead of `var type: PersonalityType`.
2. When add answers, use like this: `Answer(text: "Healthy", type: [.extrovert, .fit])`